# Webservice that configures sets of apps and tracks composite pricing

Tags: web-apps, web-development

We are looking for a website/service that configures sets of apps and composites prices. It would be of great help if some independent body clarifies what the financial consequenses are of a certain constellation of apps (sets); not just prices of single apps.
What we are looking for is a site that has this more or less on board:

- Business app filtering
- Configure a set
- Accepts parameters like number of users, expected gigabytes
- Calculate composite price

What we have investigated so far:

- Of course: Google is our friend... but did not give suitable results
- We did send the question already to Bitium, OneLogin, 1 response so far, however no hint in the right direction.
- We found getapp.com to be very informative with reviews, but there are no filters (categorisations of apps) and no financial aspects available.

Does anyone know of *any site* that does this? We are looking for a solution to assess the financial feasibility ("are we able to afford a set of apps in the long run?") once a certain composition of apps becomes successful; centrally available via Single Sign On and connected via API-bridges.

With upcoming web based solutions for Identity - and Access management (Single Sign On and more) it is possible to configure many possible web-apps "together". Some overlap in functionality and you would want to compare them; functionality-wise and price-wise before investing too much upfront.

The most common property of pricing SaaS based apps: As the number of users / gigabytes increases costs will increase too. Every app has it's own price model though: A few apps together and your composite pricing model is a nightmare...

Comment: I found http://www.cloudswave.com/. This site has a comparison tool, but does not have the desired functionality that assesses the costs of sets of apps when the number of users goes up.